# How can I use the IF in Firebird with a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to write an IF statement in my stored procedure, but I have no idea how.

`TIPO_DOCUMENTO` can be `'FAC'` or `'DEV'`, if `TIPO_DOCUMENTO` is `'FAC'`, I will use the `total_neto`, `total_impuesto`, `total`, `costo` and `precio` as is. But if I have `'DEV'`, I will need the negative values of those fields.

```
begin
/*FILTRO RANGO DE FECHA*/
IF (P_FECHA_DESDE='0' OR (P_FECHA_DESDE IS NULL) OR (P_FECHA_DESDE='')) THEN
     V_FECHA_DESDE = CAST('01/01/1900' AS DATE);
ELSE
     V_FECHA_DESDE  = CAST(:P_FECHA_DESDE AS DATE);

IF (P_FECHA_HASTA='0' OR (P_FECHA_HASTA IS NULL)OR (P_FECHA_HASTA='')) THEN
     V_FECHA_HASTA = CAST('12/31/3999' AS DATE);
ELSE
     V_FECHA_HASTA  = CAST(:P_FECHA_HASTA AS DATE);

/*FILTRO RANGO DE VENDEDORES*/
IF (P_VENDEDOR_DESDE IS NULL) THEN P_VENDEDOR_DESDE = '';
IF (P_VENDEDOR_HASTA IS NULL) THEN P_VENDEDOR_HASTA = LOWER('ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ');
IF (P_VENDEDOR_HASTA = '') THEN P_VENDEDOR_HASTA = LOWER('ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ');
IF (NOT ((P_VENDEDOR_DESDE = '') AND (P_VENDEDOR_HASTA = LOWER('ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')))) THEN
IF (P_VENDEDOR_DESDE = P_VENDEDOR_HASTA) THEN
    V_WHERE = V_WHERE || ' AND  (VEN.VENDEDOR_CODIGO = '''||P_VENDEDOR_DESDE||''')';
ELSE
    V_WHERE = V_WHERE || ' AND  (VEN.VENDEDOR_CODIGO BETWEEN '''||P_VENDEDOR_DESDE||''' AND '''||P_VENDEDOR_HASTA||''')';

/*CICLO DE LA CONSULTA SQL*/
FOR SELECT
    a.tipo_documento,
    a.documento,
    b.nombre as vendedor,
    c.producto_codigo,
    c.producto_nombre as descripcion,
    c.cantidad,
    d.departamento_codigo,
    c.deposito_codigo,
    (c.descuento_unitario * c.cantidad) + (c.descuento_unitario_2 * c.cantidad) + (c.descuento_unitario_3 * c.cantidad) +(c.descuento_unitario_4 * c.cantidad) as total_descuento,
    c.total_neto,
    c.total_impuesto,
    c.total,
    a.cliente_codigo,
    a.cliente_nombre,
    e.direccion,
    estado.nombre,
    ciudad.nombre, 
    c.costo_unitario * c.cantidad as costo,
    c.precio_unitario * c.cantidad as precio
    from ventas a
    join vendedores b
    on a.vendedor_codigo = b.codigo
    join ventas_detalles c
    on a.correlativo = c.correlativo_principal
    join productos_terminados d
    on d.codigo_producto = c.producto_codigo
    join clientes e
    on a.cliente_codigo = e.codigo
    join ubicacion_geografica estado
    on estado.codigo = e.estado
        and estado.tipo = 'E'
    join ubicacion_geografica ciudad
    on ciudad.codigo = e.ciudad
        and ciudad.tipo = 'C'
    where a.fecha_emision between :V_FECHA_DESDE and :V_FECHA_HASTA
INTO
    :TIPO_DOC,
    :NUM_DOC,
    :VENDEDOR_NOMBRE,
    :PRODUCTO_CODIGO,
    :PRODUCTO_NOMBRE,
    :CANTIDAD,
    :DEPARTAMENTO,
    :DEPOSITO,
    :DESCUENTO,
    :TOTAL_NETO,
    :TOTAL_IMPUESTO,
    :TOTAL,
    :CLIENTE_CODIGO,
    :CLIENTE_NOMBRE,
    :CLIENTE_DIRECCION,
    :ESTADO,
    :CIUDAD,
    :COSTO,
    :PRECIO
do
begin
if (TIPO_DOC = 'DEV') then
    total_neto = -total_neto ;
    total_impuesto = -total_impuesto ;
    total = -total ;
    costo = -costo ;
    precio = -precio;

suspend;
end
end
```

Now I can only get the negative values, regardless of whether I have FAC or DEV.

Comment: you can neither "add" or "subtract" nothing from nothing. You only can add TO SPECIFIC SOMETHING or subtract FROM SPECIFIC SOMETHING. It is absolutely undecipherable WHAT your procedure wants to do. What is it you try to achive with you procedure ???

Comment: I have 2 types of TIPO_DOCUMENTO, FAC and DEV, when I have a DEV I need to turn negative the amount, but when I have a FAC I need the number in positive. In any case I will add the result.

Comment: you can not just "add the result." - it is impossible to add nowhere, nakes no sense. You have to add TO SOME SPECIFIC SOMETHING. **Where** do you add to ??? Show the data before procedure, show how you call it, and show what datra is after procedure was called

Comment: also why you even do any loops `FOR SELECT X into :VAR_1` ??? why not just do without loops? `SELECT SUM(X) into :VAR_1`. And to account for your If - add the correction coefficient. `SELECT SUM(X) * :COEFF, SUM(Y) * :COEFF into :VAR_1, :VAR_2`;  Then you can do for example `VAR_3 = VAR_3 + VAR_1; VAR_4 = VAR_4 + VAR_2;`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the signature and any variable declarations. Also reduce your code to a [mcve] (eg use a single table and reduce the number of columns and simplify your query and remove all unnecessary code) and provide example data, expected output and actual output for that reduced example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` is syntactically wrong for what I think you want to do. The indentation of the following suggests that all those statements should depend on the `if` condition:

```
if (TIPO_DOC = 'DEV') then
    total_neto = -total_neto ;
    total_impuesto = -total_impuesto ;
    total = -total ;
    costo = -costo ;
    precio = -precio;
```

In reality only the first statement after the `if` belongs to the `if` condition. In other words, it is actually

```
if (TIPO_DOC = 'DEV') then
    total_neto = -total_neto ;
total_impuesto = -total_impuesto ;
total = -total ;
costo = -costo ;
precio = -precio;
```

If you want all those statements to depend on the `if`, you need to define a block using `begin` and `end`:

```
if (TIPO_DOC = 'DEV') then
begin
    total_neto = -total_neto ;
    total_impuesto = -total_impuesto ;
    total = -total ;
    costo = -costo ;
    precio = -precio;
end
```

See also [IF ... THEN ... ELSE](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-ifthen) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just an advice, using syntactic highlighting.

```
FOR SELECT
....
do
if (TIPO_DOC = 'DEV') then
    total_neto = -total_neto ;
    total_impuesto = -total_impuesto ;
    total = -total ;
    costo = -costo ;
    precio = -precio;
```

This code has few problems with me.

1. If within loop - often it may slow down execution. So if IF condition is not dependent upon loop data - if it is invariant - it might make sense to move If outside of loop.
2. Future compatibility - what would you procedure do if for example `TIPO_DOCUMENTO = 'BE-BE-BE'`? Should not happen today? But it can happen tomorrow as new functions would be added to the program. It even can happen today because of some bug.

Personally i would do it different way:

```
DECLARE VARIABLE COEFF SMALLINT;
....

COEFF = CASE TIPO_DOC 
   WHEN 'DEV' THEN -1
   WHEN 'FAC' THEN +1
   ELSE :COEFF / 0 /* generate error if prohibited value */
END;

-- shorthand
-- COEFF = DECODE( TIPO_DOC, 'DEV',-1, 'FAC',+1, :COEFF / 0 );

FOR SELECT....
DO
  total_neto = COEFF*total_neto ;
  total_impuesto = COEFF*total_impuesto;
....
```

---

More strange things: `P_VENDEDOR_DESDE = '';` - thus this variable is some text type, like `VarChar` or `CHAR` or `BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT`.

Then why `VEN.VENDEDOR_CODIGO BETWEEN '''||P_VENDEDOR_DESDE||''' AND '''||P_VENDEDOR_HASTA||'''` ??? 
Why not just `VEN.VENDEDOR_CODIGO BETWEEN P_VENDEDOR_DESDE AND P_VENDEDOR_HASTA` ?

Comment: `TIPO_DOC` is dependent on the loop though. Its value is from one of the columns selected (`a.tipo_documento`). Although a better solution would probably be to just do this in the query itself.